# Finding solutions to $x^2\equiv a$ mod $8k+1$, $8k+1$ prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, legendre-symbol, quadratic-reciprocity

For $N=4k+3$ prime, a solution can easily be found as $x=a^{k+1}$. This is because:

$x^2=a^{2k+2}=a^{2k+1}\cdot a=a^{\frac{N-1}{2}}\cdot a\equiv a\mod N$.

A similar construction can be done for $N=8k+5$.

From http://course1.winona.edu/eerrthum/math347/SquareRoots.pdf, a method is presented for primes of the form $N=8k+1$, but it utilizes an auxiliary number $n$ that is a quadratic nonresidue modulo $N$.

My question is: is there a nontrivial* way to compute a solution to $x^2\equiv a\mod N$ without the use of a known quadratic nonresidue $n$?

*without checking every positive integer less than $N$ etc.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it's worth mentioning that finding a quadratic nonresidue is quite easy in practice—just pick random integers and test them using the Legendre symbol, which is lightning fast to calculate with a smart implementation.

Comment: Ya I know they can be found via reciprocity, but my gripe is that the former methods are deterministic whereas the latter $8k+1$ method relies on the "random" choice(s) of a base(s), hoping they are a quadratic nonresidue.

Comment: Note that after the author did the case $4k+3$, the case $4k+1$ was not taken up as the next case. That's already a clue. The author then does the case $8k+5$ but not the case $8k+1$. Another clue. Presumably the author could have done the case $16k+9$ but not case $16k+1$. And so on. At that point, the author introduces a rather cool (but nontrivial) method that works for all odd primes $p$, and although partly non-deterministic, the algorithm as a whole is reasonably efficient. If there was an easy, deterministic way to do the case $4k+1$, why would the author bother with the case $8k+5$?

Comment: This is why I asked for a method without the use of quadratic nonresidues (not necessarily an entirely "deterministic" one). Additionally perhaps some properties of $8k+1$ may be able to help us here, for example the identity that $8k+1=x^2+2y^2$.

Comment: My comment was intended to suggest that, most likely, there is no easy, deterministic method for any of the cases $4k+1,8k+1,16k+1,...$, since for example, if there was an easy, deterministic method for the case $4k+1$, then the two cases $4k+1$ and $4k+3$ would cover all primes greater then $3$, and there would be no need to go further. Would the author deliberately choose to hide such a method if such a method was known?

Comment: Oh I see. There may be a harder deterministic method though. :)